# Rails action mailer working with a regular gmail account, but not with a gsuite business account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, google-workspace

I'm currently using these smtp settings to send emails with action mailer

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'myusername@gmail.com',
    password:             'mypassword',
    authentication:       'plain'
  }
```

And this actually works. However, I don't want to use my personal gmail account to send emails. I'd rather use my business email. I'd like to have something like this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'username@mydomain.com',
    password:             'appspecificpassword',
    authentication:       'plain'
    # enable_starttls_auto: true
    # ^ ^ remove this option ^ ^
  }
```

Here is some information

- First, I've already created an app password on my gsuite account, and I'm pasting the password into the smtp settings block.
- I have 2 factor authentication enabled on my gsuite email, which is why I'm using an app specific password.
- When I run the second block of code (my gsuite email) I get an Net::SMTPAuthenticationError error and it also says that the Username and password were not accepted...
- I don't know if this has anything to do with anything, but I got my domain from namecheap and I'm handling my domain with DigitalOcean

Any help is appreciated.

Other Post's I've used:

- [Using ActionMailer with a company Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503203/using-actionmailer-with-a-company-gmail-account?rq=1) (Did not work)

I assume I'm not getting any answers because my question is worded incorrectly. If you have any suggestions for the question itself, I would love feedback. This is something I've been researching for a while now, and I can't find any solutions that work anywhere.

Comment: This may help https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2014/02/building-rails-based-app-for-google.html

Comment: @angel Please check my answer

Comment: @Angel Garcia, my only solution was to "Allow less secure apps" even when using the double factor authentification.

Comment: hi!! did you find another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below configuration

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'sample.com',
  :user_name            => 'notifications@sample.com',
  :password             => 'sample123',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true }
```

If the above configuration does not work for you please do the below

there is this configuration in gmail that **COULD** be the cause of the problem. I am not sure it would result with an `error: SMTP: authentication failed`

this is the [guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to allow the unsafe apps

> ## Change your settings to allow less secure apps into your account.
>
> We don't recommend this option because it can make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to the "[Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)" section of my Account.
> 2. Turn on **Allow less secure apps**. (Note: If your administrator has locked less secure app account access, this setting is hidden.)

also I found similar post for this problem, for example a similar issue was solved in this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735206/rails-4-netsmtpauthenticationerror-535-5-7-0-authentication-failed#25794003)

Comment: But this isn't secure right? I thought you had to enable app specific passwords and use your app specific password on the smtp settings and enable 2f authentication. I did all of that and yet the password still isn't working.

Comment: The above is same is working for me please restart your server once.

Comment: and your using 2f authentication and an app specific password for you rails app? And your also using Rails 5.2?

Comment: @AngelGarcia please try to send the email to your business email I think your domain is not verified

Comment: I'm pretty sure my business email is setup correctly. I'm receiving emails no problems. I would really feel better if I could use an app-specific password instead of having to turn `less secure apps` on. I'm trying to follow the steps as best I can, however, my authentication is failing because Gmail is not accepting my email and password.